# Is it possible to schedule an async and sync function at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, scheduler, python-telegram-bot, apscheduler

**Code of reference**:

```python
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder

def function_one(args):
    #DO SOMETHING

async def function_two(args):
    await #DO SOMETHING ELSE

scheduler_one = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler_two = AsyncIOScheduler()

scheduler_one.add_job(function_one, 'interval', minutes = 5, args = ( ,))
scheduler_two.add_job(function_two, 'interval', minutes = 1, args = ( ,))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(API_KEY).build()

    scheduler_one.start()
    scheduler_two.start()

    application.run_polling()
```

**Module versions**:

- Python v3.10.6
- python-telegram-bot v20.0a1
- apscheduler v3.9.1

**Output**: Only `scheduler_two` starts working, whereas `scheduler_one` will be ignored. Therefore, only one scheduler is activated.

**Description of the problem**: I need both `function_one` and `function_two` to work periodically. `function_two` depends on the python-telegram-bot [`Bot`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a1/telegram.bot.html) class which needs to be awaited.

**Attempts**:

- I have tried using `scheduler_one` for both but I get an error message regarding `function_two`

```bash
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py:85: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'function_two' was never awaited
2022-09-15T14:46:30.247039+00:00 app[worker.1]:   del work_item
2022-09-15T14:46:30.247040+00:00 app[worker.1]: RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

- Then, I tried using `scheduler_two` for both, but only `function_two` works.
- Finally, I tried calling `function_one` inside of `function_two` but it wouldn't work either.

Therefore, my question is whether there is any way at all to run these two functions at the same time or any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to point out that `python-telegram-bot` comes with the built-in [`JobQueue`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue) which is in fact based on `APScheduler`. So setting up a scheduler yourself is likely not even necessary. Note that in v13.x, PTB uses the `BackgroundScheduler`, while in v20.x (currently in pre-release mode), PTB uses the `AsyncIOScheduler`, since v20 made the transition to `asyncio`.

Regarding coroutine functions vs normal functions as job callbacks, I have to comments:

- defining `function_one` as coroutine function as well will not affect any of the code within the function and that way you can directly use it in the `AsyncIOScheduler` (or the `JobQueue`)
- `BackgroundScheduler` is based on threading. I would generally avoid mixing threading with `asyncio`. So if `function_one` performs any I/O intensive tasks, I'd recommend to rework those to an `asyncio` based scheme.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea about JobQueue. I ended up using the functools.wraps decorator to make the sync function async. It's not the most efficient way of doing things, but it works for now.